# How to view varbyte colum data like other fields

Tags: sql, teradata

i am working on teradata 14 .
i have a table with a column defined as varbyte(100)

when i issued 
    sel * from table; in sql assistant

1 LOB information window popped up and asking File type,
                              Display as picture in answer set,
                              Directory path

even when i click yes or no , that colum data is storing in local computer as .jpg
in which i cant see any thing .

so my question is :

how to view that data like normal other fields . so that i can use where clause on that
column ?

```
NOTES: i can use this SELECT from_bytes(ssn, 'Base16')
```

but it still display ssn in .txt file , i need to open text file to see the value .

Comment: what is the filter condition that you want to apply?

Comment: @emaillenin , just where ssn='hh-bb-yy-34-56' which is present in that column

Comment: did you try `select * from table where ssn='hh-bb-yy-34-56'`?

Comment: to try i dont know what encrypted value is in that field , i could not see value . but i know it is in encrypted form .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how the data in your table was encrypted but you can change the settings of SQL Assistant to display CLOB and BLOB data in the AnswerSet window instead of an external file.

1. Go to Tools -> Options
2. Select Data Format
3. Change *Handle Binary/Byte Columns as BLOBs if size >* to value greater than your encrypted field(s) in your table.
4. Change *Handle Varhcar Columns as CLOBs if size >* to a larger value as needed.

Comment: ..size of the clob is 1048544000 for unicode..but SQL Assitant have a max limit which is very less as compared to above...

Comment: @anwaar_hell at some point it is impractical to display all that data in a SQLA result window. :)